# Spacebar doesn't work sometimes on my magento store

Tags: magento, input, keyboard

I got a work magento store (www.siberiaequipamentos.com.br), i've added some plugins by the time, i wrote some codes and I have no idea about what could be making spacebar stop working on my searchbox.

I've ignored this problem by the time but now, coding an offline messagebox, the fields of this messagebox aren't accepting spaces on it input fields...

Is there a way can I inspect the trace when I use spacebar?

Could someone tell me what is heappening?

Thanks....

Comment: Could you provide link to this messagebox?

Comment: This messagebox isn't online yet, but, open www.siberiaquipamentos.com.br and try to add a space between some words on searchbox and you'll see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to debug such problems. I'm using Chrome and this is some crude debug procedure which I would use:

1. Open the website and find an element in which problem occurs (in this case its a searchbox with id `#basicSearchField`);
2. Right-click on this element and choose "Inspect element" from a popup menu;
3. Click "Event listeners" tab on the right side of the inspector window;
4. Check "keydown" and "keypress" events and take a note of ancestor elements to which they're bound (in this case: `document` and `window`);
5. Try to disable these listeners and check if this helps. To disable listener bound to element XXX you can execute this code in console: `document.removeEventListener('keydown', getEventListeners(XXX).keydown[0].listener)`

In your case executing `document.removeEventListener('keydown', getEventListeners(document).keydown[0].listener)` restores proper functionality of searchbox. Which means that some script located at `/js/magentothem/ma.jq.slide.js` is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I helped me to find way to solve the problem!

Comment: @WilliamFerreira, then at least give me vote up. :-)

Comment: Sorry! i forgot about that!